# Javascript: search string in array then count occurrences

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using `indexOf` to search for a string in an array, how can I continue to count the number of occurences? I tried the latter but it isn't working.

```
var feed= new Array();
var feed= ["testABC", "test", "testABC"];

if (feed.indexOf("testABC") != -1) {
    for (var i=0; i < feed.indexOf("testABC").length; i++ ) {
        logInfo("found"+feed++);
    }
}
```

Comment: please add some data for `feed`.

Comment: what about `feed = ["testABC testABC"]` - two occurences?

Comment: And is `["testABCtestABC"]` one, two, or none?

Comment: You might want to take a look at the [Array iteration methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Iteration_methods). These are nearly always more appropriate than a for-loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count instances of string in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a count variable and iterate over the elements of `feed`. Then check if the element has `indexOf` unequal `-1` (means found) and count the occurence.

```js
var feed = ["testABC", "test", "testABC"],
    count = 0,
    i;

for (i = 0; i < feed.length; i++) {
    if (feed[i].indexOf("testABC") !== -1) {
        count++;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [Array.prototype.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) function:

```
var feed  = ['foo','testABC','bar','testABC','testABC'];
var count = 0;
feed.forEach(function(value){
    if(value=='testABC') count++;
});
console.log(count); //3
```

Or [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var feed  = ['foo','testABC','bar','testABC','testABC'];
var count = feed.filter( function(value) { return value=='testABC' } ).length;
console.log(count); //3
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var numOfString = 0;
var feed= new Array()
var feed= ["testABC", "test", "testABC"]

for(var i=0;i<feed.length;i++){
    if(feed[i] === "testABC")
       numOfString++;
}
console.log(numOfString);
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
var feed = ["testABC", "test", "testABC"],
count = feed.filter(function(v) { return v.indexOf('test') > -1; }).length;
```

EDIT: removed duplicate feed = feed.
also, I had startsWith instead of indexOf. It should work now.

Comment: You've written `var feed =` twice. But even corrected it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple and straight forward solution. You may want to make it a function in the case that you want to reuse your code.

```
var feed= new Array()
var feed= ["testABC", "test", "testABC"]
var count = 0

// ensure that our array contains the key you want prior to scanning it
if(feed.findIndex("testABC") >= 0) {
    for (var i=0; i < feed.length; i++ ) { 
    if(feed[i] === "testABC") count++
  }
}

alert(count)
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to all the ways the other stated, if you are using ES6 you can use the 'for of' loop to iterate all the array's values:

```
var numOfString = 0;
var feed = ["testABC", "test", "testABC"];
for(let currentString of feed) {
  if(currentString.indexOf('testABC') !== -1) {
    numOfString += 1;
  }
}
console.log(numOfString);
```

Answer (score 2):

It can be achieved with one line of code using ES6 arrow function expression:

```
var feed = ["testABC", "test", "testABC"], count = 0;

feed.forEach((v) => v === "testABC" && count++);

console.log(count);  // 2
```

Comment: @OlegMikhailov, I don't think so. That is not too complicated case to talk about readability. Too simple

Comment: Yeah, but who knows what this function becomes in future... It is always a good time to talk about readability). Programs are written for humans then.

Comment: @OlegMikhailov, " but who knows" - nobody knows. When someone will ask for the extended and complex case - I'll write new solution. But for now, "one-line" solution will be also good

Answer (score 1):

If `feed = ["testABC testABC"]` counts as two occurences of "testABC", then I suggest the following code:

```js
var feed = ["testABC", "test", "testABC"];

var count = (feed.join('').match(/testABC/g) || []).length;

console.log(count)
```

See also [How to count string occurrence in string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009756/how-to-count-string-occurrence-in-string)

Arbitrary search strings would need escaping for special regex characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Code:

```js
const feed = ["testABC", "test", "testABC"];
const count = feed.toString().match(/testABC/g).length;

console.log(count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply use `reduce()` method:

```js
    const feed = ["testABC", "test", "testABC", 'testABC'];

    const count = feed.reduce((acc, val) => (acc[val] = acc[val] + 1 || 1, acc), {})['testABC']

    console.log(count)
```