# How to count string occurrence in array of strings?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Given array :

```
var arr = [ 'male01', 'woman01', 'male02', 'kid01', 'kid02', 'male06'];
```

**How to count the number of `male` in that array ?**

Expected result : `3`.

---

Note: I just edited the problem to make it simpler.

Comment: Have you tried something or you want us to code for you?

Comment: I have no idea where to go I guess there is some forEach or Match or something which is most convenient. I though of for loop and search/match, with incremental counter but it seems quite an heavy coding for such task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript: search string in array then count occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686802/javascript-search-string-in-array-then-count-occurrences)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count instances of string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array)

Comment: Given the number of -1 on my question I'am going to delete this question. Please report refer yourself to [Javascript: search string in array then count occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686802/javascript-search-string-in-array-then-count-occurrences) or [Count instances of string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```js
var arr = [ 'male01', 'woman01', 'male02', 'kid01', 'kid02', 'male06'];

console.log(arr.filter((item) => item.startsWith('male')).length);
```

Comment: @NinaScholz - Agreeing it to be a better way. Updated. Thanks.

Comment: How do you know all the occurrences are at the start of the word? I would instead use `String.prototype.includes()`

Comment: @YosvelQuintero - Makes sense, however, as per the data provided, the above will work well too. Thank you.

Comment: Given the number of -1 on my question I'am going to delete this question. Please report your answer to [Javascript: search string in array then count occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686802/javascript-search-string-in-array-then-count-occurrences) or [Count instances of string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array) so I can +1 your elegant answer.

Comment: No worries. Thank you for the warning

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr = [ 'male01', 'woman01', 'male02', 'kid01', 'kid02', 'male06'];
var count=0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
if(arr[i].indexOf('male')>-1)
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and the [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

Code:

```js
const arr = ['male01', 'woman01', 'male02', 'kid01', 'kid02', 'male06'];
const count = arr.toString().match(/male/g).length;

console.log(count);
```

Comment: Given the number of -1 on my question I'am going to delete this question. Please report your answer to [Javascript: search string in array then count occurrences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37686802/javascript-search-string-in-array-then-count-occurrences) or [Count instances of string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array) so I can +1 your elegant answer.

Comment: I have market you question as Favorite and given the +1.. But is ok, you can delete and use the solution on your personal project.. Thanks for the message

Comment: I didn't expected my answer to be down voted. Thanks for your code it's indeed the level of elegance I was looking for !

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate upto length of array if string found increment the value of counter. Like following.

```js
var arr = [ 'male01', 'woman01', 'male02', 'kid01', 'kid02', 'male06'];
var stringCount = 0;
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
   if(arr[i].indexOf('male')>-1){
      stringCount++;
   }
}
console.log(stringCount);
```

Comment: Please refrain from copy pasting other people's answer