# How to check for multiple occurrences of word in string or array

Tags: javascript

I need to get the count of a specified set duplicate words in a string.

I can return the occurrences of one word but I am stuck at multiple words.

```
const sData = 'am=1&am=2&pm=1&pm=2&pm=3&ac=1&dc=1';
const aData = sData.split('&');

const nData = aData.filter(el => el.includes('am')).length;
```

This returns `2` which is expected but I need to do the same for `pm`,`ac` and `dc` and as I understand `includes` does not accept multiple values.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array

Comment: can you show a sample input and output expected for mutiple values

Comment: Can you provide what you expect your output to look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can encompass repeated work using **functions**!

```
const countOccurrencesOf = (word, search) => {
  return word.filter(el => el.includes(search)).length;
};
```

Now, you can re-use this function for all of your other string finding needs:

```
countOccurrencesOf(aData, 'pm');
countOccurrencesOf(aData, 'ac');
countOccurrencesOf(aData, 'dc');
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for, is a recursive function. Within the example you have provided, I'm assuming your parsing URL Query variables. So, let's pretend that the following are your delimiters: & or =.

This function shows a general idea of what it seems like you're trying to acheive.

```
 function containsDuplicates(string,delimiter,foundDuplicates){
    var str = string.split(delimiter);

    if(foundDuplicates.includes(str)){
        return true;
    }else if(string.indexOf(str) < string.length){
        foundDuplicates.push(str);
        return containsDuplicates(string,delimiter,foundDuplicates);
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you pass in foundDuplicates as 'am, pm, ac, dc'?

Comment: In that example, foundDuplicates would be an empty array, you can pass in null for it. 

And if you want all of the duplicates returned, you can return foundDuplicates instead of return true or return false.

Answer (score 1):

Try using map instead:

```
const sData = 'am=1&am=2&pm=1&pm=2&pm=3&ac=1&dc=1';
const aData = sData.split('&');

// define the stings you want to count
const nData = {am: 0, pm: 0, ac: 0}

// iterate over the split input data
const val = aData.map((obj) => {
    // iterate over the nData
    Object.keys(nData).forEach((count) => {
        // if the input contains the count, add to the count
        if (obj.includes(count)) nData[count]++;
    })
})
console.log(nData); // returns: { am: 2, pm: 3, ac: 1 }
```

Reduce would probably work as well!

Answer (score 1):

- Create an array of keywords you want to find.
- Create a regex by separating the words with a `|`.
- Use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) get all the matches for the keywords specified.
- Create a `counter` object. Loop through the array of matches and count each occurrence

```js
const str = 'am=1&am=2&pm=1&pm=2&pm=3&ac=1&dc=1',
      toFind = ['am', 'pm', 'ac'],
      regex = new RegExp(toFind.join("|"), "g"),
      matches = str.match(regex);

console.log(matches)

const counter = {};
matches.forEach(m => counter[m] = counter[m] + 1 || 1)

console.log(counter)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```