# Count length of each string in an array

Tags: javascript

This is my JS code:

```
var arr = ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox"];
    
console.log(arr.length);
```

I want an output like this:

```
[3, 5, 5, 3]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count instances of string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use map function of array to get the new resultant array according to the operation performed for each element in the array

```js
var arr = ["the", "quick", "brown", "fox"];

console.log(arr);

const resultArray = arr.map((element) => {
   return element.length;
});

console.log(resultArray);
```

Comment: or shorter: arr.map(({length}) => length);

Comment: @Chris yes, my first answer was shorter also like arr.map(element => element.length) but I edited it to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by looping through the array and printing its length

```
var arr=["the", "quick", "brown", "fox"];

for (var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
console.log(arr[i].length);
}
```