# Count number of the same input value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have these fallowing inputs :

```
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="5">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
```

How can I count the number of the same value ?

For example:

The value 23 appears 4 times

The value 23 appears 3 times

The value 5 appears once

The value 9 appears twice

I know I can loop using

```
$(".type_id").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val())
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array this will help

Answer (score 2):

You can use a **dictionary** to count the number of times a value is repeated.

```js
let inputs = document.querySelectorAll(".type_id");
let frequency = {};

for(let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
  if(frequency[inputs[i].value]){
    frequency[inputs[i].value]++;
  }else{
    frequency[inputs[i].value] = 1;
  }
}

console.log(frequency);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="5">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select inputs, create an array from that NodeList and apply `reduce` method to get count for each value as one object. you can do the same with jquery selector `$('.type_id')`

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.type_id')

const count = [...inputs].reduce((r, { value }) => {
  r[value] = (r[value] || 0) + 1
  return r;
}, {})

console.log(count)
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="5">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const numbers = Array.from($('.type_id'), input => parseInt(input.value, 10));
const result = numbers.reduce((result, number) => {
  result[number] = result[number] || 0;
  result[number]++;
  return result;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

or you can use lodash's [countBy](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#countBy) like so:

```js
const numbers = Array.from($('.type_id'), input => parseInt(input.value, 10));
const result = countBy(numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you need to memoize all values, it's better to use object for it.

```
const inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('type_id')

const result = Array.from(inputs).reduce((acc, rec) => {
  const currentValue = rec.value
  if (typeof acc[currentValue] !== "undefined") {
    return {...acc, [currentValue]: acc[currentValue] + 1}
  }
  return {...acc, [currentValue]: 1}
}, {})

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, 2, 2))
```

Here my working is jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/ahs21myo/2/

Answer (score 0):

A oneliner

```js
const frequencies = [...document.querySelectorAll('.type_id')]
  .reduce( (acc, val) => 
    ({...acc, [val.value]: +(acc[val.value] || 0) + 1}), {});
    
console.log(frequencies);
```

```html
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="5">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="9">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="23">
<input type="hidden" class="type_id" value="11">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using `Dictinary`:

```
  var dictinary = []; // create an empty array

    $(".type_id").each(function () {
        var val = $(this).val();

        if (dictinary[val])
            dictinary[val]++;
        else
            dictinary[val] = 1;
    });

    console.log(dictinary)
```