# Count empty strings in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Having this input:

```
const myArray = ["", "", "test"];
```

I want to count the number of empty strings, for the above example it is 2.
A complicated method would be

`myArray.map(a => a.length === 0)` which returns a new array of true and false and after that to count them.

Is there a shorter method to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Count instances of string in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9996727/count-instances-of-string-in-an-array)

Comment: If you can count `true` and `false`, why can't you count the emptystring `""`?

Comment: Check this thread - [How to count certain elements in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120931/how-to-count-certain-elements-in-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the undesired values and then check the length of the resulting array:

```
const emptyCount = myArray.filter(a => a.length === 0).length;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `filter` and use `length` in this way:

```js
const myArray = ["", "", "test"];

let count = myArray.filter(x => x.length === 0).length;

console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter() to get a filtered array with only empty string item. Then you can get the number of item in the array with `length`.

```js
const myArray = ["", "", "test"];

const output = myArray.filter(el => el === "").length;

console.log(output);
```